# SQL Server-Is It possible 'lock waits and timeouts high but average wait time does not'?

Tags: sql-server

I use Windows Server 2008 Standard and SQL Server 2008 version.

I always thought that if the 'Lock Waits' number was high, the 'Average Wait Time' number would be high as well.
In addition, it is a situation that even lock timeouts occur.

However, this time Lock Waits was high, but Average Wait Time was not.
Is this possible? In what cases is this possible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are mixing up counts and duration
lock waits/sec is a count of events per second
average wait time - is the duration of the sum of the lock waits / the number of waits in that second.

so the 2 indicators are only correlated if an increase in the number of waits leads to an equivalent increase in the duration of these waits - but there is no reason for this to be true, Also worth noting that there are many different sorts of lock within these numbers - row, page, extent, table etc